# Solr Autoscaling policy for ADDREPLICA is not functioning in Metric Based Triggers

Tags: search, solr, lucene, autoscaling

I am using Solr version 7.5. The Autoscaling policy for ADDREPLICA is not functioning in Metric Based Triggers in this version. The "preferredOperation" was given "ADDREPLICA" for a sample metric trigger and it wasnt functioning. However, the operation MOVEREPLICA was working as expected. Any idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According [to the tests it should work as expected](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_7_5/solr/core/src/test/org/apache/solr/cloud/autoscaling/MetricTriggerIntegrationTest.java). Try to set logging to the `DEBUG` level for `org.apache.solr.cloud.autoscaling` and `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.cloud.autoscaling` to see if anything stands out. Please add the relevant configuration for your trigger as well.

Comment: Apparently it looks like the parameter "shard" is mandatory for the operation "addreplica" to function for a metric based trigger, I added it and looks like its working. On the other hand, the operation "MOVEREPLICA" worked smoothly without this parameter. Thanks again Mats !

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it - that way it'll be properly tracked as an answer to the problem (and it's perfectly fine to answer your own question).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it looks like the parameter "shard" is mandatory for the operation "addreplica" to function for a metric based trigger, I added it and looks like its working. On the other hand, the operation "MOVEREPLICA" worked smoothly without this parameter. Anyways I am good now l.